# Present perfect for an event that took place 2 days ago

Tags: tense, present-perfect

> FUTURE PUNX, DIÄT, DESTROYER, SHIT & SHINE
>
> Hi friends. Just a few records – but some big news J The DIÄT record release show w/ Merchandise **has been amazing**! Thank you all for coming! Tonight we will celebrate.....

Could you explain me why present perfect for this event the"record release show" as it took place 2 days ago  , it was 26th august and I received the email 28th august.
is it because he thanks people for coming now(effect on present) that present perfect is justified?

Comment: Who wrote the email? This appears to be a German event, and in German the present perfect is a perfective, the equivalent of an English simple past. In the expression *Thanks for VERBing* the *-ing* form is a gerund, without either tense or aspect: it may be used with propriety for a perfected past event.

Comment: @StoneyB: Are you suggesting the grammar nazis will come gunning for me if I say *The amount of rain that fell in August has been amazing!* on September 1st? It seems a perfectly reasonable usage to me, provided the amazing event(s) were quite recent, and continue to amaze.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a repetitive eventuality: it was amazing throughout a timespan which continues to the present. But a single event?Even if last night's party still amazes me I'm not gonna say "The party's been amazing."

Comment: @StoneyB: There's a fine line somewhere in there. What about *The donations at last night's Policeman's Ball have been amazing*? Does it matter if the speaker is actually the treasurer - still opening envelopes stuffed full of donations, and being constantly amazed? (Or maybe it matters whether the ball is in aid of *secret police* as opposed to *grammar police!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Lessee how finely we can split this hair: I'd expect that to come out as *the donations **from** last night's Policeman's Ball*, and I'd have no problem at all with that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Wouldn't it be better to think of grammar as the *expressive capabilities* of a language, and grammarians not as policemen but as voice coaches?

Comment: @TRomano: I dunno. People wax lyrical about the US Constitution, for example (fine stirring words, blah blah). But it's so vaguely/badly/archaically worded that apparently millions of people can disagree over whether it actually specifies that Americans have a basic human right to carry guns and shoot each other. And ***poetry*** - often regarded as the "showcase" vehicle for exploiting the expressive capabilities of a language - habitually rides roughshod over standard grammar/syntax (which we mostly learn by example/use, not by being formally *taught*).

Answer (score 1):

You read the e-mail two days after the show took place.  Somebody might read it 1 day after, somebody - a week, etc.  There is no definite time of the event mentioned in the text, so there is no *need* to use Past Indefinite.

Your assessment is correct that as of the time of writing that e-mail, the "now", it did not matter *when* the event *took place*, what mattered is its outcome, its evaluation as "amazing".